# Running a jar as docker image and using this jar in other java application

Tags: java, docker, jar, microservices

I have a jar that do some business functionality and developed as a standalone component. Now I want to use it as a Microservice hosted as docker image. I was able to create a docker image by following the tutorial as:
https://dzone.com/articles/run-simple-jar-application-in-docker-container-1

Now I have two problems:

1. How to call the methods of the classes in this Jar in other java applications
2. how to do the integration testing?

I am asking this as I need to take a decision if I should convert this JAR to a REST based application or it can be used as a Microservice in its actual (jar) based packaging.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the article it had

`CMD java -jar HelloWorld.jar`

I want you to imagine the logical extension of hello world that takes arguments and can output "Hello Steve" instead.

change that line to

`ENTRYPOINT ["java", "--jar", "HellowWorld.jar"]`

and

`CMD ["World"]`

Comment: Could you please be more specific around my questions. Like if I have many classes in my Jar running as Docker image, how I will access the method of a class from another Java file outside the Docker image? Does creating a REST interface is the only option we have?